Samurai Jack episode where monster turns into prince
I have seen part of this episode dubbed in Arabic. I only saw the last 2 minutes of it.
Samurai Jack was fighting a giant monster with a body of black rocks, and red lines. I am not sure what happened, but the monster was hit in the abdomen. then he was transformed into a handsome prince, then he aged very quickly and collapsed, letting go of his sword.
He asked Samurai Jack to hand him his sword back, then died. Some angels or something came and picked him up.

It must be S01E08 Jack and the Lava Monster

Jack survives a cave full of challenges only to find an ancient warrior, cursed by Aku, longing to reach Valhalla.

From http://samuraijack.wikia.com/wiki/Lava_Monster

While traveling through a field one day, Samurai Jack began to hear a voice calling out to him. The voice soon led him into a treacherous cavern full of booby traps and the bones of many before him. After successfully reaching the end, the Lava Monster revealed himself and battled Jack. However, seeing the monster's eagerness to fight, Jack refused and sheathed his sword. The monster begged Jack to continue fighting, then told Jack of his past and his desire to pass on to Valhalla, the only way to reach it being to fall in true combat with another warrior. Jack decided to resume fighting the Lava Monster to try and free him. After a fierce battle, Jack defeated him and freed the warrior of his shell, but the warrior began to rapidly age. The warrior thanked Jack, and when he passed on, a pair of Valkyries descended in a beam of light to carry the Warrior to Valhalla. Before he left the cavern, Jack drew on the warrior's obelisk a picture of the Warrior and the word FREE in stylized runic. When Jack resumed his journey, the warrior could be seen looking down at him from the heavens in the company of the gods of Asgard, Odin among them.

